# ./gradlew tasks gives me a "build scan failed due to network error 'java.net.ConnectException: Network is unreachable"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When running `./gradlew tasks`, I get the following error despite having a good network connection, `Publishing build scan failed due to network error 'java.net.ConnectException: Network is unreachable (connect failed)`.

Here is the full error:

```
% ./gradlew tasks
Configuration cache is an incubating feature.
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Calculating task graph as no configuration cache is available for tasks: tasks

0 problems were found storing the configuration cache.

See the complete report at file:///Users/.../configuration-cache-report.html

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not create service of type BuildCacheController using .createBuildCacheController().
   > Network is unreachable (connect failed)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 498ms

Publishing build scan...
Publishing build scan failed due to network error 'java.net.ConnectException: Network is unreachable (connect failed)' (2 retries remaining)...
Publishing build scan failed due to network error 'java.net.ConnectException: Network is unreachable (connect failed)' (1 retry remaining)...

A network error occurred.

If you require assistance with this problem, please report it to your Gradle Enterprise administrator and include the following information via copy/paste.

----------
Gradle version: 7.5
Plugin version: 3.10.2
Request URL: https://sitegoeshere.com/scans/publish/gradle/3.10.2/token
Request ID: ****
Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Network is unreachable (connect failed)
----------

Configuration cache entry stored.
```

Answer (score 0):

[face palm]

With Gradle Enterprise Build Scans, make sure you are on the right corp Wifi network and not the guest Wifi network. (My laptop defaulted to the guest.)

Hopefully, this saves you an hour of troubleshooting. :-P